# Is it better to register floating contextual menu click listener in Adapter or in ViewHolder? [ANDROID]

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm planning to create a floating contextual menu for my app in a fragment after onLongClick and I also have a custom Adapter extending from RecyclerView.Adapter and a custom holder extending from RecyclerView.ViewHolder.
I found out there are 2 options to register :

**Option 1** : Registering the listener inside onCreateViewHolder method by `holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener` and retrieving any ViewHolder instance variable I want by calling `holder.getSomeVariable()` inside the event handler and set it to current instance variable so I can retrieve it from Activity/Fragment (because I can get reference of adapter from my fragment).

The advantage I notice is that it allows me to declare the implementation `onCreateContextMenu()` and `onContextItemSelected()` method and override them in my Fragment/Activity, which allows the reusing of the existing provided method and get the `ViewHolder` variables inside the `onContextItemSelected()`.
I notice the downside is that we need to create extra setter and getter method in the adapter (because we cannot reference ViewHolder instance from Activity/Fragment).

**Option 2** : Registering the click listener inside ViewHolder. According to [`this website`](http://androidessence.com/recyclerview-vs-listview/) ,the advantage is it allows more explicit click listener (I also have other listeners registered in the ViewHolder class, so they're group together which makes the code structure looks better).
However, I notice the downside from using this way is we cannot declare `onCreateContextMenu()` and `onContextItemSelected()` inside Activity/Fragment anymore because we cannot get the viewholder reference from Activity/Fragment, we can only get adapter reference. As a result, the readability is a bit worse. (I have a contextual_menu.xml, so will need to do the inflation in the viewholder as well instead of in fragment/activity. Is inflation of XML in viewholder even a correct practice?)

From what I understand, in general scenario , it's better to register listener in ViewHolder (Option 2).
But in my context, which method (Option 1 or Option 2) should I apply? Does the general scenario still apply (should I apply Option 2)?
Also are there any more advantages and disadvantages from those 2 listed options?

Answer (score 0):

I use it in `Activity` or `Fragment` that way

1- Create `interface` like that:

```
public interface OnItemLongClickListener {
    void onItemLongClick(int position);
}
```

**EDIT:**

2- In your <del>Adapter</del> **`ViewHolder`** class create a reference like that:

```
private OnItemLongClickListener listener;
```

3- In adapter create `setter` method to initialize `listener` which will call another `setter` method in `ViewHolder` class like that:

```
class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolder>{
    .
    .
    .
    .
    public void setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener listener){
        viewHolderObject.setonItemLongClickListener(listener);
    }
}
public class YourViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    .
    .
    .
    .
    public void setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

4- In your ViewHolder in method onLongClick() do this:

```
@override
public boolean onLongClick(View v){
    listener.onItemLongClick(getAdapterPosition());
}
```

5- In your Activity Do the contextual menu staff

I hope this help you.!

Comment: My ViewHolder is in a seperate class from the adapter, how can I get the reference to the  instance 'listener' from ViewHolder class?

Comment: is it available to move `ViewHolder` class inside adapter ??

Comment: It is possible to move the ViewHolder to inside the adapter class. However, I'm looking for implementation that lets me use the listener variable outside the adapter class.

Comment: @Mr_RexZ see my edited answer, if you found it useful please mark as an answer

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but pardon me for being relatively new in Andorid, may I know how can I get the reference to viewHolderObject in adapter's setOnItemLongClickListener method? Since as far as I know, the viewholder object is only available for referring **inside** the onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder method if I were to access the holder variable inside the adapter class.

Comment: @Mr_RexZ OK that was my error .. you can set the listener to the holer in onCreateViewHolder method